# Uri class is very brittle and seems to throw exceptions excessively

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, uri

I'm writing a Web spider and noticed that the `Uri` class is incredibly brittle.

A lot of anchor `href` attributes contain stuff like `'/'`, but the `Uri` class chokes on a lot of is. For example:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("/");
```

> Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.

Obviously, I'd prefer my code to be robust. In cases where the `href` value is a partial path, I'm using the `Uri` class to make it absolute. But that won't work if it's choking.

Has anyone else dealt with this. Is there a way to make the `Uri` class a little more reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Uri.TryCreate()` is really what I'm looking for.

When parsing pages downloaded from the Internet, there's no telling what a link will contain. Since you don't want your code to throw an error every time if finds something bogus, `Uri.TryCreate()` simply returns `false` if the given string was not valid.

Answer (score 0):

The URI scheme (protocoll for URL) is **not optional**, according to Wikipedia:

> A non-empty scheme component followed by a colon (:), consisting of a sequence of characters beginning with a letter and followed by any combination of letters, digits, plus (+), period (.), or hyphen (-). Although schemes are case-insensitive, the canonical form is lowercase and documents that specify schemes must do so with lowercase letters. Examples of popular schemes include http, https, ftp, mailto, file, data, and irc. URI schemes should be registered with the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA), although non-registered schemes are used in practice.

Your example code of `Uri uri = new Uri("/");` is thus not confirming to the rules.

This exception throwing is not excessive, as it prevented you from entering something *verifyably* invalid. At best you could argue for [vexing exceptions, but really it sounds more like boneheaded](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/) ones.

Comment: For what I'm doing, the exceptions are excessive. But I found I was able to use `Uri.TryCreate()` for something a little more robust.

Comment: @JonathanWood What you are building there is not (yet) a URI. It will maybe become part of URI laster, as you concatenate other stings to it There is no other point to starting without shema or not just adding the leading slash with the shema then that.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for `System.Uri(string)` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Uri__ctor_System_String_) only to accept *absolute URIs*, not "*relative URIs*" (more properly called *relative references* to a URI; see secs. 1.2 and 4.2 of RFC 3986), and will throw an exception upon encountering a relative reference such as `/`.

Comment: Yeah, I see that. I was just trying to figure out the workaround for those who don't want out code to fail. Looks like `Uri.TryCreate()` is probably the answer.